# JavaScript multiple instances

Tags: javascript, object, multiple-instances

I'm trying to create multiple instances of a JavaScript "class" or object but it seems to be acting as a singleton... Could someone assist me with the following code?

```
        (function() {
            /*
             * Canvas object
             */
            var Canvas = function( el ) {
                _self = this;
                _self.el = el;
            }
            Canvas.prototype.init = function() {
                _self.el.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
                _self.el.addEventListener( "mousedown", _self.onMouseDown );
            }
            Canvas.prototype.onMouseDown = function() {
                console.log( 'onMouseDown: ', _self.el );
            }

            var cOne = new Canvas( document.getElementById('one') );
            var cTwo = new Canvas( document.getElementById('two') );
            cOne.init();
            cTwo.init();
        })();
```

Comment: How is it acting as a singleton? May we see your HTML. Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) perhaps.

Comment: nothing obviously wrong.  Please explain what behavior you're seeing thats incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When not using `var` on a variable declaration, it becomes a global variable. So when you create a new instance, it updates the global variable.

An alternative to this approach is to simple make a `el` an object property:

```
var Canvas = function(el) {
    this.el = el;
};
```

***[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k4EdA/)***

---

Moreover, you should consider binding your `.onMouseDown` method to the current object. Use this instead:

```
this.el.addEventListener(..., this.onMouseDown.bind(this));
```

or this:

```
Canvas.prototype.init = function() {
    var self = this;
    ...
    this.el.addEventListener(..., function() {
        self.onMouseDown.call(self);
    });
};
```

Comment: Except then I cannot access it with event handlers because `this` is no longer referencing the canvas object...

Comment: @user1960364 See my edit. I used `.bind` to bind it to the current canvas object.

Comment: .bind is not supported in IE8 - is it?

Comment: @user1960364 If you don't want to use bind you can also use `.call`. I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
var Canvas = function( el ) {
   var _self = this;
    _self.el = el;
}
Canvas.prototype.init = function() {
    this.el.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    this.el.addEventListener( "mousedown", this.onMouseDown.bind(this) );
}
Canvas.prototype.onMouseDown = function() {
    console.log( 'onMouseDown: ', this.el );
}
```

no `var` you make _self a globle val

Comment: When adding `var`, I receive an error that `_self` is not defined when trying to access it from other methods within Canvas

Comment: so you can see i change all other _self into this, and when adding handle, make a bind--- google for farther info

Comment: .bind is not supported in IE8 - is it?